# how to change the icon dynamically for each user after login

Tags: java, html, jira

In my home page there is one logo of my company. After login to the system by different user, how to change the logo dynamically for different user. i want to change the icon of my page dynamically. After login of each user the logo will be changes dynamically

Comment: You have to change the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag that renders the logo.  Typically that will mean JavaScript and/or JSP or some other dynamic web design technology.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the images for each group / User at server location.
Like User1 - User1.jpg
User2 - User2.jpg
Once we get user login into application, we will have to read and get this particular image from server to make it dynamically.
If user 1 login our application will find user1 images on that location.
Please let me know if sounds good.